# Java wait() notify()

Tags: java, многопоточность

Есть класс с одним методом `synchronized` и два потока, взаимодействующих с объектом этого класса. Когда один поток находится в состоянии `wait()`, а второй поток возобновляет его работу через `notify()`, то, получается, что оба потока продолжают свое выполнение? Тогда какой из них получает доступ к монитору?

Comment: Тот, кто первый "добежит"

Comment: наводите на метод notify курсор и нажимаете ctrl+Q (IDEA), и читаете, что там написано `The awakened thread will not be able to proceed until the current thread relinquishes the lock on this object.`. Т.е. поток с wait будет ждать, пока поток с notify не покинет synchronized блок

Comment: @IR42, спасибо за пояснение.